# Fiddler AutoResponder error with Dynamics 365 web resource

Tags: typescript, debugging, fiddler, dynamics-365, webresource

I'm trying to debug Dynamics 365 TypeScript web resource deployed in the Dynamics 365 online instance. I made an AutoResponder rule which exactly matches the URL, but still, I'm getting error 404.

[Traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K98P.png)

[AutoResponder rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZ4i.png)

I also enabled the capture and decryption of HTTPS content and disabled Caching.

Thanks,
Arsen.

Comment: While it is should of course be possible to make AutoResponder work, you should take a look at [Imposter](https://github.com/gotdibbs/Imposter.Fiddler) for Fiddler instead. It is tailored for doing local development of TS/JS for Dynamics 365. Take a look at [Speeding Up Web Resource Development with Imposter for Fiddler](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/sonomapartners/archive/2016/09/08/speeding-up-web-resource-development-with-imposter-for-fiddler)

Comment: Thanks, Henrik. This works for me. It's still interesting why AutoResponder is not working properly, but anyway Imposter has some cool advantages over that, so I'll stick with that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `Rule Editor` source, You need to write tje spcific location of the source.map file and not only the directory:

c:\Users\USER\source\repos\WebResources\WebResoures\ **Account.js.map**